# Webmock: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webmock

When I am trying to mock a http request with the following code snippet.

```rb
mocked_payload = { test: 'testing' }.to_json

stub_request(:get, application_url)
  .with(body: platform.user_credentials)
  .to_return(status: 200, body: mocked_payload)
```

I receive this.

[image]

Does anyone know how this can be solved? I reduced the mocked_payload to figure out if something is wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because of `.with(body: nil)`, when webmock tries to parse body json, but body is not defined for GET-requests

Comment: (byebug) platform.user_credentials
{:username=>"this-is-a-partner-id", :password=>"this-is-an-api-key"}

Inside the user_credentials is no nil. I use the same user_credetials for a stub_request in the same before block.

Comment: It was the whole `.with(body: {})`. Removing it solves the issue, I added an answer. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After I dug more into the request I figured out how to solve it:

The http `get` request was stubbed with a body, which is never used in the "real" request.

Removing this line `.with(body: platform.user_credentials)` solved the issue.